# PHP Red Bean MySQL multi-value binding evaluation in getAll()

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have an array in php containing strings, which I want to use in a query with Red Bean MySQL in the following manner:

```
$someString = '\'abc\',\'def\',\'ghi\'';
R::getAll("select * from table where name not in (:list)", array(':list'=> $someString));
```

The problem is that the list is not being evaluated correctly no matter how I set the values in the array string, and the names abc, def, ghi are returned in the result. I've tried the following:

```
$someString = '\'abc\',\'def\',\'ghi\''
$someString = 'abc\',\'def\',\'ghi'
$someString = 'abc,def,ghi'
```

running the query in the SQL server manually works and I don't get those values returned, but running it within the php code with redbean is not working, and it seems that the list is not being interpreted correctly syntax-wise.
Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

Comment: You are going to have to do a string search functions to check if the `name` is in :list variable that is a string. RedbeanPhp does have functions that allow you to do what you want using PHP arrays as parameter, Check the documentation:  'finding' and 'IN-queries' and R::genSlots

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks ! it worked perfectly, kind of a hassle in complex queries because I had a value that appeard 4 times in the query and then a dynamic list so I had to create an array with 4 duplications of the same value and then merge it because according to the documentation you can't have named parameters and positional parameters mixed in the same query, but the important thing is that it works !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to RyanVincent's comment I managed to solve the issue using positional parameters in the query, or more specifically, the R::genSlots function.

replaced the following:

```
$someString = '\'abc\',\'def\',\'ghi\'';
R::getAll("select * from table where name not in (:list)", array(':list'=> $someString));
```

with:

```
$someArray = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi');
R::getAll("select * from table where name not in (". R::genSlots($someArray) .")", $someArray);
```

This creates a $someArray length positions for parameters in the query, which are then filled with the values in the second parameter passed to the getAll function.
Notice that in this case I used a set content array (3 variables) but it will work dynamically with any length array you will use.

Furthermore, this can also work for multiple positions in the query, for example:

```
$surnameArray = array('smith');
$arr1 = array('john', 'pete');
$arr2 = array('lucy', 'debra');

$mergedVarsArray = array_merge($surnameArray,$arr1);
$mergedVarsArray = array_merge($mergedVarsArray,$arr2);

R::getAll("select * from table where surname != ? and name in (." R::genSlots($arr1).") and name not in (". R::genSlots($arr2) .")", $mergedVarsArray);
```

This code will effectively be translated to:

```
select * from table where surname != 'smith' and name in ('john','pete') and name not in ('lucy', 'debra')
```

Each '?' placed in the query (or generated dynamically by genSlots() ) will be replaced by the correlating positioned item in the array passed as parameter to the query.

Hope this clarifies the usage to some people as I had no idea how to do this prior to the help I got here.

Comment: Excellent answer, Shows that you understand what is happening at code generation and execution. Thanks for sharing the answer as it will help others.